# Dynamic Sound Generation in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

I want to generate sound by writing a code in actionscipt 3. All I know is that I have to use an array and store the sound data in that, but I don't know how exactly I should do so!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adobe does a pretty good job covering it here, it looks complicated but its not. 
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WSE523B839-C626-4983-B9C0-07CF1A087ED7.html

if you want to generate an exact note this code would do that, the noteFreq variable would be the frequency of the note you want to play which you can look up here http://www.phy.mtu.edu/~suits/notefreqs.html
In this example 261.63 = the note middle C
Just adjust that variable as you like and it will generate that note

```
var noteFreq:Number = 261.63;
var generatedSound:Sound = new Sound();
generatedSound.addEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, sineWaveGenerator);
generatedSound.play();
function sineWaveGenerator(e:SampleDataEvent):void
{
     for (var i:int = 0; i < 8192; i++) 
     { 
          var n:Number = Math.sin((i+e.position)*noteFreq*2.0*Math.PI/44100.0);
          e.data.writeFloat(n);
     }
}
```

Edit:
As for what you said about arrays you could store those frequencies in an array and have it cycle back through the array using that same method. This example would play the mario brothers theme song

```
var generatedSound:Sound = new Sound();
var songArray:Array = [164.81,164.81,164.81,130.81,164.81,196.00,98.00];
var songIndex:int = 0;
generatedSound.addEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, playSong); 
generatedSound.play();

function playSong(e:SampleDataEvent):void
{
       for (var i:int = 0; i < 8192; i++) 
       {
           var n:Number = Math.sin((i+e.position)*songArray[songIndex]*2.0*Math.PI/44100.0);
           e.data.writeFloat(n); 
       }
       songIndex++;
       if(songIndex == songArray.length)
       {
           songIndex = 0;
       }
}
```

Comment: Thanks doug! I want to create a windowed application. How should I proceed. I tried looking for it but I am totally new to actionscript. I would be obliged if you just guide me through making this code run in Flash Builder. I am including flash.media.sound and flash.events but still I don't know on which mode should i run my app to create a swf file.